# synchronise many microcontrollers

Tags: microcontroller, rs485, synchronization

In my project i'll use modbus protocol for serial communication. There are more than 320 slaves which seperated equally in 2 groups(see image). Every 16 slaves are powered from the same supply and isolated from others galvanically(Master'll be isolated from all the slaves). 
[image: i attached a pic to make it clear]
My first question is if there is a problem in this design?

Secondly I want to synchronise all the slaves via 10ms period pulses that are derived from master microcontroller. How can i achieve a robust synchronisation(what type of bus, single or differential signal, where to isolate)?

Here is an alternative one:
[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAopC.png)

Comment: Is a time-triggered Modbus feasible? Are you in control of the slaves code? As I read, Modbus isn't really master-slave as the slaves are allowed to initiate communication themselves, which would make a sync message unreliable.

Comment: Modbus won't carry out synchronisation. In fact my question is which type of line can be used to synchronise so many slaves(considering EMI issues)? And my other question is if this structure is effective in terms of EMI

Comment: You mean the modbus driver layer won't allow you to detect  e.g. a broadcast message that is sent every 10ms for sync on the application layer?

Comment: yes it won't. What i'm not certain is the structure of the bus.

Comment: Sorry to appear stubborn ;) but wouldn't it be possible to send a broadcast write to a holding register in all slaves which is reserved as an upcounting sequence watchdog? You could not only spare the extra sync lines but also do a communication line qualification e.g. detecting a non-continuous watchdog can tell you if some parts of your network suffer from EMI, a frozen watchdog means the slave is on its own (and can shutdown gracefully) etc. The synchronization requirement can't be too sharp, can it? Which deviation of local clocks in your slaves is tolerable?

Comment: You are right, i decide to use r485 bus for synching. 1-2 microsecond is easily tolerable. What i worry about is execution delay deviations. Because i get chars in interrupt. After about 4 char delay i start to process the frame in for() loop. What if i change master uart tx pin to pwm and change slave uart rx pins to external interrupt. This way i can use the same bus for synching.

Comment: Umm.... firstly, I didn't expect your sync requirement to be *that* tight. 2 microseconds? Really? And secondly: as you have a repeater between your master and the 16-drop slave line, playing with the levels will likely not work.

Comment: Voltage levels'll be the same. I'll send 10ms clock pulses instead of serial data. What can go wrong if slaves know when it is serial data or clock pulses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many things can go wrong here. For starters, it will take a looooooong time for you to poll each and every one of your slaves. And your isolators will easily introduce delays beyond 2us to your sync signal.

Can you briefly tell us what are you trying to do specifically, eg. synchronized motion control? There are other alternatives used in industrial solutions.

Most of the synchronized motion control used in industrial systems are used to replace mechanical cams and eccentric gears, and thus usually called "electronic camming" in this field. Here's a list of techniques I had come across in my last job

1. A PLC which outputs multiple pulse trains, each commands an individual servo/stepper motor driver. The PLC will have to store all the motion profiles and do all the interpolations, so relatively simple drives can be used. But each actuator will need it's own pulse train lines, and there's just too much in your system.
2. Motor drives stores motion profile & does interpolation, and the motion is advanced/reversed by an external pulse train. This is a technique used in Delta Automation ASDA and Schneider Electric Lexium 23 model industrial servo drives. The motion profiles are either burnt into the drive's EEPROM beforehand, or written in through MODBUS. This is very close to what you are trying to do, but the difference here is the external sync pulse train is on a separate wire.
3. Real Time Ethernet. The target positions are periodically written to each drives at a specific interval. This can be done very rapidly at 100Mbps. As for the latency that occurs when writing to different drives, there is a built in mechanism that measures the latency of each drives, and this is then compensated accordingly later. Cool eh? The one that I had saw, but never really used is EtherCAT by Beckhoff.

I worked mostly with method 2 in the past, and from those experience you needs might not need to be so stringent. Here are my recommendations.

1. It will be perfectly fine if your sync signal is delayed a little if your mechanism has no risk of collision if the timing is off by a little. But lost pulses cannot be tolerated as one of the actuators will be out of phase. Don't scrimp on your sync & communication cable quality, shielded twisted pair if possble, and connect them properly.
2. If the communication line is not too long, isolators are not needed. I had worked with lines up to 8 meters without the need for isolators or repeaters. Instead I am more worried about the number of spur (branch) connection on your RS485 bus. If possible, connect everything to your 2 main buses directly.
3. If this is a production system, there might be a problem. When the system is running in sync motion mode, there is no way to monitor the actuators as the communication lines are now occupied. This will not be acceptable on a real world application, but if this is just a proof of concept design, go for it.

Comment: Yes i want to do synchronized motion as you guess. Firstly i want to send many positions to many slaves using modbus protocol(no problem if it takes half an hour). After all the positions are loaded i'll tell all slaves to get ready using modbus again(a repeated broadcast message). Here i plan to change master tx pin to pwm and slave rx pins to external interrupt(seeking pulse periods). So i wont need a parallel line. What are the alternative industrial solutions? Probably an experimented way would be better.

Comment: Control systems are not the usual thing that people talk about here. I am just the odd one out. It might be more helpful if you can find a forum for industrial automation engineers as synchronized motion is part of their bread and butter. Probably there is one around you, just ask for the one who knows PLC. Good luck!

Comment: Hi ckchai, all your recommendations are reasonable. I was thinking on a bus as in your 2nd recommendation(i added a picutre to my question about this bus type). Each bus length is 120 meters at least. Connected slave number is not less than 160 for each bus. All slaves'll use isolated ISO3082 rs485 IC. I propose to supply all isolated parts from a single 5V supply that is placed next to master.

Comment: I don't see much problem with this new design.  Your transceiver's unit load are also sized correctly. The isolation maybe an overkill, but if cost is not an issue, no problem. Just be careful with the long bus length. Use high quality cable to reduce losses. Terminate properly & put in failsafe pull up/pull down to your bus. As for the DC supply, I suggest you use a higher voltage to deal with line loss, then convert to 5v on the slave side.